# Can the Enum TimeUnit be passed as an argument to a method?

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible that an Enum like [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) be passed as an argument to a method?  I am writing a Java method that takes a long  as a duration argument and was curious if there is a better way to do it.  Basically, I want to pass something to my method that is a little bit clearer/explicit on what duration I am actually trying to pass to it.   I don't want to write my own wrapper since I am sure something already exists out there, doesn't it?

So, something like this, which obviously doesn't work because unit doesn't store any "state", does it? :

```
void timedMethod( TimeUnit unit ) {
   long duration = 1000;
   long val = unit.toMillis(duration);
}
```

Comment: yes Enum can be used as method argument.

Comment: Yes, you should try it :)

Comment: Why don't you try? `public static void time(TimeUnit unit){}`

Comment: In spite of their peculiarities, enums are "just" regular objects, so yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course. For example one of the signatures of [`Future#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is:

```
public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

And the implementation probably looks like:

```
long millis = unit.toMillis(timeout);
//do something with the number of milliseconds
```

So if you call `get(1, SECONDS)`, `millis` will be 1000.

Comment: So, your saying unit can be passed and then there is some way to get the "stored value" from it?  If so, can you elaborate?

Comment: @djangofan what "stored values" are you talking about? You seem to be misunderstanding what an enum is in Java

Comment: @fge - I don't think I am misunderstanding the Enum.  My understanding of Enum is that it can only convert values and has no ability to store.  Therefore, the reason why I asked my original question, since I want to know if there is some other java object/api that you would recommend for this sort of thing.  Maybe "Duration" class is what I am looking for?

Comment: @djangofan you are definitely misunderstanding; an enum is a regular class, with the difference that only a defined set of instances (your enum "values") are initialized when you load the class. You can have an enum with parameters in the constructor and they can even have methods (`TimeUnit`, for instance, has methods on it).

Comment: @djangofan I have added an example that probably answers your question.

Comment: Well, I actually see some stuff in java 1.8 that might be what I need?    java.time package?

Comment: @djangofan It depends on what you want - you could indeed use a Duration or a number (int, long) with a ChronoUnit. In the end it achieves similar goals so you should pick the one that is more readable when you call the method.